# Create a vector of enumeration values

Tags: matlab, oop, vector, concatenation, enumeration

I have an enumeration class. I wanted to make a list of some of the enumerations, for example,

```
myEnumList = [MyEnum.Hearts; MyEnum.Diamonds];
```

I get the error,

> Error using vertcat
>   Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

I have also tried making it a cell array and get the same error message. Is it not possible to have a vector of enumerations?

Just to be clear I know you can get a list of all the members of an enumeration class but this is not what I am after.

**Update**

My enumeration

```
 classdef MyEnum
   enumeration
     None
     Default
     Hearts
     Diamonds
     Spades
     Clubs
   end    
 end
```

Comment: So the class is called `MyEnum` and you're using `myEnum` (different capitalization) in your example? Perhaps `myEnum` has some wrong size?

Comment: Apologies it should have been MyEnum not myEnum, a typo

Comment: If the enumeration is defined as you have shown, the code above does not result in an error. In other words - your error cannot be reproduced (I'm using R2019a).

Comment: Ah yeh I just copied that into my matlab and it works. As far as I can see its the exact same as my actual code, strange

Comment: So... problem solved?

Comment: yes thanks will mark your answer correct. I just deleted the file and copied a new one and it worked... no idea why it didn't in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example [MATLAB's example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html) for enumerations:

```matlab
classdef WeekDays
   enumeration
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
end
```

It is generally possible to do:

```
>> [WeekDays.Tuesday; WeekDays.Monday]

ans = 

  2×1 WeekDays enumeration array

    Tuesday
    Monday 

>> {WeekDays.Tuesday; WeekDays.Monday}
ans =

  2×1 cell array

    {[Tuesday]}
    {[Monday ]}
```

So if it doesn't work for your class, I can think of several explanations:

- Your class or some class you inherit from overrides one of the concatenation functions which makes it impossible to do this specific operation.
- Enumeration members do not correspond to scalars, or do not correspond to consistently sized objects/arrays (shouldn't be an issue with cells, though).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I just updated my question to show my enumeration. I don't think I'm inheriting from any other class. Do I need to give the members a scalar number?